# Как передать аргумент функции в другую функцию?

Tags: php, ооп

```
class A {

    public function b($val) {
    }

    public function c() {
    }
}
```

как передать аргумент **$val** из *функции b* в *функцию с* , при обычном методе и при статическом ?

```
class A {

    public static function b($val) {
    }

    public static function c() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как простой пример, можете создать переменную в объекте:

```
 class A {
        protected $params;

        public  function b( $val ) {
            $this->params = $val;
        }

        public  function c() {
            print_r( $this->params );
        }
    }
```

**static** вариант

```
 class A {
        protected static $params;

        public static function b( $val ) {
            self::$psrams = $val;
        }

        public static function c() {
            $val = self::$psrams;
            print_r( $val );
        }
    }
```